# Is the verb tense correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

You might solve some issues by coming here but facing new problems.

I'm not sure if the verb 'facing' is used correctly in this sentence, is it?

Comment: I doubt if it's used correctly. You should write _.... but you might/could **face** new problems_.

Comment: It definitely isn't. Your sentence makes it sound as if 'facing problems' is part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is in simple past, so you should keep verbs in base form.

> You might solve some issues by coming here but might also face new
> problems.

However, if you want to include 'facing' in your sentence, then you should modify what precedes it by adding some phrases. For example, you can write it this way:

> "You might solve some issues by coming here, though *only at the cost
> of* facing new problems."

This way 'facing new problems' collectively acts as a noun, or, to be precise, a gerund phrase.

Other ways of writing your sentence:

> You might solve some issues by coming here, but you would also face new
> problems.
>
> You may solve some issues by coming here, but you may also face new
> problems.
>
> You may solve some issues by coming here, but you will also be facing
> new problems.